# Using ListUsers to get all users that have or haven't verified their email addresses - AWS Cognito

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get the list of all cognito users that have the *email_verified* attribute, and then all of the users that don't have it (I'm also ok with getting all users, having the *email_verified* attribute with the user so that I can just make the two lists). My approach so far has been to do something like this

```
client.list_users(
    UserPoolId=pool_id,
    AttributesToGet=['email_verified']
)
```

This works as long as all users have the *email_verified* attribute. If the user however doesn't have this attribute I get this error:

> ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when
>   calling the ListUsers operation: One or more requested attributes do
>   not exist.

I have tried to to use the Filter parameter in the ListUsers function however it doesn't seem to like the *email_verified* attribute.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

In case it matters, I am tyring to do this in python

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is old, but I will answer just in case someone else is also searching for the answer (like I was yesterday).

If you just omit AttributesToGet parameter when you call listUsers, it will return list of users with all of the attributes for each user. Then you can just loop through that list and pick those users who have email_verified attribute, depending whether it is true or false.

Comment: Thank you! their API & documentation is very poor to say the least.

Comment: Also, it should return null or something when there's no attribute, not crash...

Answer (score 0):

The AttributesToGet field is basically a projection, a set of attributes you want the de facto search to return. If it isn't there, it can't get it, hence the error.

Could you just get every user that has an email attribute, maybe? Then split the list based on whether or not that attribute exists in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute "status".

Status should show you "Confirmed" and "Unconfirmed" users.

Here is the list of attributes that you can search on. No other attributes are supported for search.

username (case-sensitive)

email

phone_number

name

given_name

family_name

preferred_username

cognito:user_status (called Enabled in the Console) (case-sensitive)

status (case-insensitive)